# Change week dynamic in PHP for listview

Tags: php, date

I want to create a list where a week is displayed and the values of each day are displayed in the section of the day.

First I tried to create the dynamic week change so that you can press a button to show the week before or the next week.
Now I have this code and in the output I have a week from Sunday to Saturday.

Now here is my problem, since I always have Sunday as the first day the week that is output is also always the one from Sunday, so the week before the actual week.
I tried to change the week output in the variable `$dow` with `date('N')` from `date('n')`. Unfortunately this did not work.

How do I have to change my code to show / output the correct week from Monday to Sunday?

Note: under `$ts += 0 * 86400 * 7;` on the `0` you can change the week starting from the current week.

```
$ts = date(strtotime('last monday'));
$ts += 0 * 86400 * 7;
$dow = date('N' , $ts);
$offset = $dow;

//the output is currently only for testing
$ts = $ts - $offset * 86400;
$week = date('W', $ts);
echo "<p>$week</p>";
for ($x=0 ; $x<7 ; $x++,$ts += 86400) {
    echo '<p>' . date("d.m.Y", $ts) . '</p>' ;
}
```

**Output to the code and current week**
[image: Output to the code and current week]

Comment: I don't fully  understand your problem, but have you tried simply using strtotime() instead of adding `0 * 86400 * 7;` ?  You can use `date(strtotime($day . ' + . $x . ' days'))` and just increment one day at a time

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel - see https://fullcalendar.io

Comment: @ADyson I know about fullcalendar, I also have it in use. For this case, unfortunately, this is not an option, because this is not a calendar in the classical sense to be

Comment: @Dave the code works, but the output week goes from Sunday to Saturday and not from Monday to Sunday, which makes the week number for the days from Monday to Saturday no longer fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something simpler, like this?

```
<?php
$currentDate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('last monday'));
for ($x=0 ; $x<7 ; $x++) {
    echo '<p>' . $currentDate . '</p>' ;
    $currentDate = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($currentDate . ' +1 day'));
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was just thinking too complicated